# What are the data behind the claims of high predictive power of biomarker tests for sleep deprivation?

Tags: sleep, metabolomics

[Today's (6th May) Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/may/08/blood-test-for-sleepy-drivers-could-pave-way-for-prosecutions) is reporting that blood tests for tiredness have achieved high predictive power:

> Prof Clare Anderson, at Monash University, in Melbourne, Australia, who is leading efforts to develop a blood-based test, said: “When you look at the major killers on the road, alcohol is one of them, speeding is another, and fatigue is one of them. But even though the solution to fatigue is quite simple, which is to get more sleep, our capacity to manage it is impaired because we don’t have tools to be able to monitor it like we do with alcohol.”
>
> Anderson’s team has identified five biomarkers in blood that can detect whether somebody has been awake for 24 hours or more with greater than 99% accuracy.
>
> Follow-up studies conducted in conditions closer to real-world situations have also indicated that these biomarkers can detect whether or not someone has slept. “We still get close to 90% accuracy at being able to detect sleep loss, which is pretty high considering all the things that are going on in people’s lives beyond just sleep,” Anderson said.

What is the data behind these statements?

### Previous Reading:

Pubmed search "Clare Anderson[Author] biomarker" gives two papers, [one assessing a classifier to detect lack of sleep](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-019-47311-4) but using blue light and skin temperature and nowhere near the reported predictive power.

The second appears to be a preliminary study for this work: [Circadian and wake-dependent changes in human plasma polar metabolites during prolonged wakefulness: A preliminary analysis](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-019-40353-8) but does not seem to support such predictive power, from the abstract:

> We observed metabolites that were significant at the group-level but not significant in a single individual, and metabolites that were significant in approximately half of individuals but not group-significant.
>
> Owing to large inter-individual variation in rhythm timing and the magnitude and direction of linear change, acrophase and slope estimates also differed between group- and individual-level analyses.

[Google Scholar gives 34 papers that cite this](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&cites=38819866561422837&scipsc=1).  Of these one appears relevant, but has very different numbers:

[Developing preliminary blood metabolomics-based biomarkers of insufficient sleep in humans](https://doi.org/10.1093/sleep/zsz321)

This uses 65 biomarkers to identify those with insufficient sleep, but reported far lower predictive power that is well below what would be required for law enforcement and is very far from "close to real-world situations":

> The top-performing biomarker model was developed by linear SVM modeling, consisted of 65 compounds, and discriminated insufficient versus adequate sleep with 74% overall accuracy and a Matthew’s Correlation Coefficient of 0.39. The compounds in the top-performing biomarker model were associated with ATP Binding Cassette Transporters in Lipid Homeostasis, Phospholipid Metabolic Process, Plasma Lipoprotein Remodeling, and sphingolipid metabolism.

Other papers that seemed relevant, with particular emphasis on work authored by Prof Clare Anderson, do not obviously have the data.  I include a summary of the ones I looked at, for completeness but if anything they seem to support the difficulty for getting the sort of predictive power that would be necessary to reach the legal threshold of beyond reasonable doubt:

[Using a Single Daytime Performance Test to Identify Most Individuals at High-Risk for Performance Impairment during Extended Wake](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-019-52930-y)

Identifying individuals particularly susceptible to sleep deprivation.  The existence of such people would seem to be a challenge for any such biomarker based test.

> Laboratory-based studies have demonstrated significant inter-individual variability in the response to sleep loss due to extended wake, such that some individuals are able to maintain high levels of neurobehavioral performance on tasks of sustained attention, even when they subjectively report sleepiness whereas other individuals appear to be particularly vulnerable to sleep loss.

[Circadian lipid and hepatic protein rhythms shift with a phase response curve different than melatonin](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-022-28308-6)

This does show five biomarkers used to measure sleep, but does not describe their use for prediction.  It does show [a graph of how they vary over time](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-28308-6/figures/3), and the variation does not look conducive to such accurate predictions, though I know modern classifiers can spot things the human eye cannot.

[Individual metabolomic signatures of circadian misalignment during simulated night shifts in humans](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.3000303)

Looks at biomarkers during sleep disruption, but does not seem to support the quote predictive power:

> On the individual level, the response to the night shift protocol was highly diverse, with phase shifts of rhythmic metabolite profiles ranging from a 0.2-h advance in one subject to a 12-h delay in another subject, revealing an individual metabolomic signature of circadian misalignment.

[Endogenous circadian regulation and phase resetting of clinical metabolic biomarkers](https://doi.org/10.1111/jpi.12752)

Looks at biomarkers during sleep disruption, does not look at predictive power.

[Diferential Impact of Sleep Deprivation and Circadian Timing on Refexive Versus Inhibitory Control of Attention](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-020-63144-y)

Analysis of ocular motor tasks throughout 40 hours of sleep deprivation.

Comment: Maybe contact the Guardian and ask them to change their terrible citation policy.